# Excel Vba Textbox Paragraph

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am creating a textbox that will work only as a guide-line, my textbox has multiline and enterkeybehaviour= True.

TextBox2 gets value from TextBox1 , now I have TextBox2 = TextBox1, I need a Carriage Return so the next inputed value will go to TextBox2 second line.

Example , i write something on TextBox1 and press Enter and the text will go to TextBox2 and do a paragraph. Can't be no overwriting as the process can be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a carriage return wit constant `vbCr`.

```
myString = "First line." & vbCr & "Second line."
```

If you want a Line Feed instead of a Carriage Return, it's `vbLf`.  Both combined are `vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text & VbLf & "Something"`

or

`TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text &  chr(13) & "Something"`

---

And some minimal example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim someVar As String
    someVar = "ale"
    someVar = someVar & vbLf & "Something"

    MsgBox someVar

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You're *everywhere* today! :)

Comment: @ashleedawg - trying hard! :)

Comment: It can't overwrite the previous lines. Your code is working but it's overwritting the previous lines , as i need it to keep feeding new lines as it also has scroll option enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextBox2.Value = TextBox2.Value & vbLf & TextBox1.Value
```

Should you wish to avoid this adding a carriage return at the start of TextBox2 for no reason, then:

```
If Not TextBox2.Value = "" Then
    TextBox2.Value = TextBox2.Value & 
    vbLf & TextBox1.Value
    Else TextBox2.Value = 
    TextBox1.Value & vbLf
End if
```